# Angular 2 RC4 router providers

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm currently updated my app to use ner Router. I did everything except protected routes.

main. ts looks like this:

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms} from '@angular/forms';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import {AuthService} from './services/auth.service';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

import {AuthGuard} from './services/auth.guard'

bootstrap(AppComponent, [appStateProvider, APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS, AuthService, AuthGuard, HTTP_PROVIDERS,,disableDeprecatedForms(), provideForms()])
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I implementeed auth.guard.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private _authService: AuthService, protected _router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

        if (state.url !== '/login' && !this._authService.isLoggedIn()) {
            this._router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

and in app routes I have:

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
   {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent 
  },  
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: ['AuthGuard']}
];

// Export routes
export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

Before that I used old routing and everything fine. Now, I got messsage 'No provider for AuthGuard!' althoug I include it in my bootstrap providers.

In my app.component.ts inside constructor I have:

```
   if (this._authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this._router.navigate(['/home']);
    }
    else {
      this._router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
```

Before I updated router if User wasn't logged in it redirected to login page, else it redirected to home page and user couldn't see home until he is not logged in. Where I'm I wrong and why I get this error since I included provider in my bootstrap method as provider?

Thanks

Comment: First time this happens to me, that a question actually answers my question. Thanks to your `auth.guard.ts` code, I was able to fix an issue I was having `canActiate(...)`. I was adding the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` on the constructor, but seems that was the wrong way, adding it on `canActivate` as a default argument worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `'` from

```
canActivate: ['AuthGuard']},
```

to

```
canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
```

I also think you should add `pathMatch: 'full'` to

```
{
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full' 
  },
```

Comment: It works now! So trivial error, but I couldn't see. Thank you! :)

Comment: Why is the path field empty string？

Comment: @WangXiao I just copied it from the question. This route matches when no path is given.